# How to override default version of library included by artifact in maven?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, artifactory, maven-dependency

I have a spring batch dependency in my pom.xml declared as below:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

There is one artifact xstream that is included by above with version 1.4.7 and it needs to be updated to 1.4.11.

It can be added as follow:

```xml
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

What is the correct way for this?I am thinking of following approach:

Both above pieces of code will be there but do I need to use < exclusions > to specifically exclude xstream artifact old version from spring-batch-core or does maven takes care of this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better way will be using `<dependencyManagement/>` tag. Dependency management will make sure the version will be maintained even if some other transitive dependency brings higher version of the dependency.

Usage:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Note: `dependencyManagement` tag is used for defining the version and scope (if not in the default scope which is compile) of a dependency it does not add the dependencies in it to you project, you must define separate `<dependencies/>` section in your pom.xml for adding dependencies to your project.

In your case it will be like.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

...

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
                <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.11</version>
            </dependency>
       </dependencies>
       ...
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
...

</project>
```

In this case `spring-batch-core` is added as a direct dependency and if it has `xstream` as dependecny you project will use `1.4.11` version even `spring-batch-core` has a different version of `xstream` as dependency.

Ref: [Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-management)

Comment: as i see, <dependencyManagement> is parent tag for <dependencies>, but i cannot use it because it may some unknown effect.Can you tell me the way i asked in question? Do i need exclusion tag or not?

Comment: thanks for updating. But do i need dependency management. There is Maven’s nearest definition logic, by which if i just add the 1.4.11(updated version) without < dependencyManagement >, it should take it?

Comment: @user124 yes you can add 1.4.11 version of xstream to your pom.xml and it will work. you dont need to add exclution

Comment: But then, do i need to exclude xstream 1.4.11  artifact from spring-batch-core?

Comment: @user124 no need to, also in exclusion version won't be mentioned only groupId and artifactId will be mentioned. You can verify which version is used by running the command `mvn dependency:list`

Comment: i specifically asked for exclusion because someone told me that if we add in exclusion, then it wont download that particular dependency and it saves n/w bandwidth and m2 size.But i cannot find anyhwere that putting in exclusion means it wont download, though it wont use is mentioned